# PHP include not working on xampp server

Tags: php

I'm trying to change a line of text on a page using php include but it's not working at all.

HTML file:

```
 <body>
     <div class="recdesc">
         <?php  include 'includes/yura-secret.php';?>
     </div>
 </body>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
   echo "<h2>Yura's secret that nobody can know</h2>";
?>
```

The html is in htdocs/html/project/index.html

The PHP is in htdocs/html/project/includes/yura-secret.php

This seems simple but I can't get it right

Comment: `htdocs/html/project/index.html` to `htdocs/html/project/index.php` <= create it; unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: In default configuration, PHP code is not executed in .html files. Make ytour first file a .php file as well …

Comment: ok, I changed it to index.php and ran it in my browser but the text still isn't showing up

Comment: Did you restart? Plus, how are you accessing it via browser?

Comment: Yeah I restarted the server and it didn't work. I'm using HTML-Kit Tools and clicking view->preview in browser -> chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that all file extensions are .php as @Fred said.

- Try using a dot at the beginning of your document like './includes/yura-secret.php'
- If you are using a framework. Like wordpress , joomla etc. absolute path of page can be different. echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ; to see the page's actual path of index.html .
- Try omitting "-" from file name and see if it is the problem.
- Change file permissions of the php file. There can be read/execute restriction.

If none of these work there most me some configuration error or a wrong file extension.

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you so much. I renamed the file to yurasecret.php and changed the file path to  './includes/yurasecret.php' and went to localhost/html/project/index.php